# Adding value to a list of item in a class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Below are my 3 methods,

```
public class abcOrder
{
    public Items items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string orderrefno { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }

}

    public class Items
    {
        public List<Item> item { get; set; }
    }
```

now i want to assign like below,

```
abcOrder.items.item.Add(new Item
        {
            orderrefno = "12345",
            sku = "sk8765",
            qty = 3
         });
```

But i am getting items as null in abcOrder.items .Please help.

Comment: You didn't initialize your `List<Item> item`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't understand why you have the `Items` class. Why not just make the `abcOrder` class have a List property?

But your problem is that you never initialized your objects. You can't use the object if you never actually created it. The easiest way to do it is in the class constructor, like this.

```
public class abcOrder
{
    public abcOrder()
    {
        items = new Items();
    }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}
public class Items
{
    public Items()
    {
        item = new List<Item>();
    }
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks.I am using json serializer.To create the json in proper format i need the Items class.many thanks